# Sum of value in all hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I sum the `amount` of all payments?

My setup:

```
# payment.rb

# metadata: text
store :metadata, accessors: [:product, :amount]
```

Results in:

```
Payment.all
#=> [id: 1, metadata: {product: "a", amount: 10}], [id: 2, metadata: {product: "b", amount: 15}]
Payment.first.metadata[:amount]
#=> 10
Payment.map(&:metadata[:amount]).sum
#=> DOES NOT WORK (25 expected)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pluck for get only metadata then use inject for sum like below

```
Payment.pluck(:metadata).inject(0) { |sum, h| sum + h[:amount] }
```

Comment: It also works well. Do you think this approach performs better?

Comment: Yes using this we are not loading all attributes of  Payment model, only load metadata and calculate sum

Answer (score 1):

You can call the sum method on an array, so if you use `Payments.all` you'll have an array of all your payments and then should be able to use the sum for the amounts on each object. It is on the [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) class as well as the [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) class.

`Payment.all.sum { |p| p.metadata[:amount] }`
or
`Payment.all.sum(&:metadata[:amount])`

Comment: `Payment.all.sum(&:metadata[:amount])` results in `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

Comment: `Payment.all.sum { |p| p.metadata[:amount] }` works. Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 methods with ActiveRecordsRelation `SUM` & `PLUCK` like shown in others answers.

but I advise you to use **SUM** it is easier to remember

Comment: Thanks for the advice!